# How do I define my own operators in TensorFlow

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow

In TensorFlow, we can use `tf.nn.l2_loss()` for doing L2 regularization. Let's say I want to define my own regularization operator for L1 regularization (call it `tf.nn.l1_loss()`). How would I go about it? I am having a hard time locating operator definitions in the TensorFlow source code.

Comment: Did you have a look at [this](http://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html)?

Comment: ah great. should have searched the API docs first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the comment suggested, there is a how-to guide for [adding an op to TensorFlow](http://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/index.html). This guide covers adding a new op that is implemented in C++. In general, you should do this in the following situations:

- The op cannot be implemented using existing TensorFlow ops (for example, `l1_loss` *could* be implemented using the existing [element-wise](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#arithmetic-operators) and [reduction](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#reduction) operators as a Python function).
- A C++ implementation is necessary for performance (or memory consumption) reasons.
- The op could be implemented as a composition of ops, **but** it has a gradient that can be computed more efficiently (or with better numerical stability) than computing the gradients op-by-op. (This is why `tf.nn.l2_loss` is implemented as a fused op in C++.)